# ASP.NET Core MVC with Identity initial migration fails with ALTER COLUMN for Identity table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

When creating a new ASP.NET Core MVC project (Core 2.2) with individual authentication, the initial migration fails with error "To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated".

The process followed is as follows:

- Create project using `dotnet new mvc -o <myapp> -auth Individual`
- Modify the connection string and change to SQlServer express running locally
- Modify startup.cs to use SQLServer instead of SQLite
- Run initial migration for identity using `dotnet ef database update` successfully
- Add new models for application
- Modify the ApplicationDbContext to contain the new DbSets for application models.
- Create a new migration `dotnet ef migration add
- Update database using `dotnet ef database update`

This operation fails with 
"To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated", related to the code below.

## Question:

1. Why does EF need to alter the column for a pre-existing table if no changes have been made.
2. How is this to be resolved.

## Assumptions:

1. I'm using the same ApplicationDbContext since I want the Identity tables to be in the same database as the application data.
2. Is it advisable to use 2 DbContexts pointing to the same DB?

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace CetaMonitor.Data.Migrations
{
    public partial class InitialModel : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "UserNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "RoleNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetRoles");

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
                name: "Id",
                table: "AspNetUserClaims",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(int))
                .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
                name: "Id",
                table: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(int))
                .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Entity",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    EntityName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    MainContact = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Address = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Province = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    TelephoneNumbers = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Entity", x => x.ID);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "UserNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                column: "NormalizedUserName",
                unique: true,
                filter: "[NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "RoleNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetRoles",
                column: "NormalizedName",
                unique: true,
                filter: "[NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Entity");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "UserNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "RoleNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetRoles");

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
                name: "Id",
                table: "AspNetUserClaims",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(int))
                .OldAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
                name: "Id",
                table: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(int))
                .OldAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "UserNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                column: "NormalizedUserName",
                unique: true);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "RoleNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetRoles",
                column: "NormalizedName",
                unique: true);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the new migration to run fine and not be dependent on the Identity tables.